# Why does GlobalSearch return different solutions each run?

Tags: matlab

When running the GlobalSearch solver on a nonlinear constrained optimization problem I have, I often get very different solutions each run. For the cases that I have an analytical solution, the numerical results are less dispersed than the non-analytical cases but are still different each run. It would be nice to get the same results at least for these analytical cases so that I know the optimization routine is working properly. Is there a good explanation of this in the Global Optimization Toolbox User Guide that I missed?

Also, why does GlobalSearch use a different number of local solver runs each run?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A full description of how the GlobalSearch algorithm works can be found [Here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/how-globalsearch-and-multistart-work.html#bsc9ege-1).

In summary the GlobalSearch method iteratively performs convex optimization. Basically it starts out by using fmincon to search for a local minimum near the initial conditions you have provided. Then a bunch of "trial points", based on how good the initial result was, are generated using the "scatter search algorithm." Then there is some more convex optimization and rating of "how good" the minima around these points are.

There are a couple of things that can cause the algorithm give you different answers:
1. Changing the initial conditions you give it
2. The scatter search algorithm itself

The fact that you are getting different answers each time likely means that your function is highly non-convex. The best thing that I know of that you can do in this scenario is just to try the optimization algorithm at several different initial conditions and see what result you get back the most frequently.

It also looks like there is something called the 'PlotFcns' property which would allow you get a better idea what the functions the solver is generating for you look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ga or gamulti objective functions within the GlobalSearch api. I would recommend this. Convex optimizers wont be able to solve a non-linear problem. Even then Genetic Algorithms dont gaurantee the solution. If you run the ga and then use its final minimum as the start of your fmincon search then it should result in the same answer consistently. There may be better ones but if the search space is unknown you may never know.